# Importing oddly-formatted CSVs with Power Query

Tags: excel, csv, powerquery

I'm trying to use Power Query to import this format of data from many CSVs.

The headers should be

```
"Time", "Container 1", "Container 1 pressure", "Container 2", "Container 2 pressure", and so on.
```

As an example:

```
Time: 00:00
Container 1: A123
Container 1 pressure: 1
Container 2: B321
Container 2 pressure: 100
...

Time: 01:00
Container 1: A123
Container 1 pressure: 2
Container 2: B321
Container 2 pressure: 90
...
```

Is there an easy way to parse this data?  The "Time" data is not formatted as a time, but the other fields are arranged in the same relative positions.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Power Query data example]

Comment: Given the lack of response, I would suggest you develop a VBA solution.

Comment: Assuming the data follows this format consistently, it's very doable in Power Query. However they said "easy" and I'm not sure making two reference tables to the source data, doing an alternate row removal, index, and merging them is "easy".

Answer (score 0):

This probably can be done easily in the UI in two steps:
1. Split initial column by delimiter ':'
    This should give you two columns, one with all the labels, and another with all the values.
2. Then pivot the labels column, but don't aggregate the values  (use pivot, not unpivot !)

That should do the trick.

Comment: That's what I thought also.  But when I tried it, it returns an error `Expression.Error: There were too many elements in the enumeration to complete the operation.`

Comment: Can you provide an example of the original CSV file with sample data? How many rows are in each CSV file?  How many containers are there between the time stamps? Is there a fix number of container or do they vary in different CVS files, or even within the same file?

Comment: Your PQ screenshot above indicates there are commas too in the CSV file. Though I can't see them in your example, which seems to be one row for <label><:><value>.

Comment: Suggest you ask the original poster that question. I assumed it was like the example included and his question.

Comment: Ooops. Did not pay attention that you were not the OP. Let's wait for his answer then.